# multiple conditions in same if statement in C

Tags: c

I write code in `c` and

I am beginner in the case I think `if(a==1,b<=8)` work like the control first check the value of `a` if and it is true then check `b`condition if both conditions are true then come into body but I think I did not know the accurate syntax to write that can anyone give me correct syntax.

here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cono.h>
#include <iostream.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void main(void)
{
    int a, b;
    printf("enter a");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    printf("enter b");
    scanf("%d",&b);
    if(a==1, b<=8)
    {
        printf("you");
        exit(0);
    }
    if(a==2, 5<b<=10)
    {
        printf("you");
    else
        printf("me");
    }
    getch();
}
```

Expected result example:

If `a` is equal to 2 so control check if `b` is less than 10 and greater than 5 if it is so, control run if's true condition if not so control run else statement

Comment: `a==2 && 5<b && b<=10`.

Comment: You probably mean `if(a==2 && 5 < b && b <=10)`. Methinks it's time for you to get your book out and read it.

Comment: Read this: [What does the comma operator , do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52550/what-does-the-comma-operator-do)

Comment: ...this kind of question was asked barely an hour ago :O

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi try this hope its work

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<cono.h>
#include<iostream.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void main(void)
{
 int a,b;
 printf("enter a");
 scanf("%d",&a);
 printf("enter b");
 scanf("%d",&b);
 if(a==1 && b<=8)
 {
  printf("you");
  exit(0);
  } else if(a==2 && 5<b && b<=10)
 {
  printf("you");
 }
else{
  printf("me");
  }
  getch();
  }
```

Comment: Please: at least format the code correctly

Comment: **`void`** `main()`?  Either write portable C, or be specific about what limitations you're imposing.  Don't just perpetuate the asker's errors without comment, please!

Answer (score 3):

`if(a==1,b<=8)` should be `if(a==1 && b<=8)`

`if(a==2,5<b<=10)` should be `if(a==2 && 5<b && b<=10)`

Please read some beginner book or some tutorial before asking such questions please.

Answer (score 1):

Logical operators in C for `or`/`and` are `||` and `&&` respectively, so you would for example rewrite

`if(a==1,b<=8)` as `if(a==1 && b<=8)` or `if(a==1 || b<=8)`.

Comment: Please explain the downvote and how I can improve my answer for you!

Answer (score 0):

What you need is `&&`

The comma operator compiles, but it does not do what you want.

```
if(a==1,b==2)
   printf("hello\");
```

will print "hello" if b is 2, regardless of the value of a.

The construct:

```
if(3<a<8)
```

does not work either. It compiles, but it does not do what you want. What it does it does is to compare 3 < a and calculate the result, which is true or false, that is, 1 or 0. After that, the result is compared to 8, and since both 0 and 1 is less than 8, this will always do what's inside the if statement.

Comment: Note that `(3<a<8)` is 1 for all `a`.